# Is it possible to run the Android emulator on other system connected via LAN?

Tags: android, android-emulator, lan

I want to test/debug my Android application on an Android emulator running on a remote system which is connected via LAN.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb kill-server
adb connect <IP>:5555
```

ip address should be the actual IP of your virtual machine running..